# How to delete a contact in Quip?

Tags: contacts, quip

I add some contact from my Gmail to Quip. Now I want to delete some of them because they are not work related. I'm using the Personal version of Quip.
How to delete a contact in Quip?

Comment: I think http://support.quip.com/entries/76881549-How-do-I-delete-contacts-in-Quip- this might get you with some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From your Quip desktop, select the account menu in the upper left of the screen, followed by "Edit Profile".

[image]

- Select "Edit Contacts" - the last option in the edit profile menu.

[image]

- Click on the red delete icon for each contact that you would like removed

You can find the answer [here](http://support.quip.com/entries/76881549-How-do-I-delete-contacts-in-Quip-).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I'll edit the answer. Thanks for guidance.